# iOS 7 UITableViewStyleGrouped missing rounded corners and cell row width fill view size

Tags: uitableview, ios7

`UITableViewStyleGrouped` does not have rounded corners like in iOS versions <= 6.
Is anyone having same problem in iOS 7? My UITableView is all written in code as it is complex. I have had a look at all the changes and guidelines and I cannot see any mention of change to the cell appearance.  Where did the corners go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS 7 is Borderless. Rounded corners are no longer available in iOS 7. Apple removed this feature. I am currently working with iOS 7 and had a discussion with apple support guys. They confirmed that this is no more supported. You can see the Settings app for an example — the table view there is group style.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have checked settings though. My brain was scrabbled.

Comment: However, on iPad the detail view still looks with rounded corners.