# Dynamically make rounded corners in UITableViewCell while supporting edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, calayer, rounded-corners, uibezierpath

I've a table, with one section (which is default behaviour). It has 5 rows by default, and can have **rows < 5**  or  **rows > 5** rows based on some user interaction with the app.

I want to make first and last cell to be rounded from top left/ right and bottom left/ right respectively.

I'm able to do it by `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer`. But the problem is comes when number of rows will get increase/ decrease. I'm not sure how to reset previously rounded cells and update a new one with particular case?

Another problem occurs when I put table in edit mode, when a delete button will be visible, it'll not show for the first and last cells. Its there, but not visible.

Here's the screenshot from the app.

1. The blue border is a table view.

[image]

2. Table without border looks like this, note rounded corners in first and last row.

[image]

3. If I wants to delete first and last cell then it'll look like below images,

[image]
[image]

4. For other cells, it'll look like this,

[image]

Can any one tell me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

---

```
- (void) roundCornersAtTopInView:(UIView *)view withRadius:(float)radius withSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIRectCorner corner = (UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight);
    UIView *roundedView = view;
    CGRect actualRect = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:actualRect byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = actualRect;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (void) roundCornersAtBottomInView:(UIView *)view withRadius:(float)radius withSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIRectCorner corner = (UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight);
    UIView *roundedView = view;
    CGRect actualRect = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:actualRect byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = actualRect;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Grouped TableView 
This will help you out to achieve your goal.

[Workaround for rounded corners of grouped UITableView, iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176179/workaround-for-rounded-corners-of-grouped-uitableview-ios7)

Comment: I'm not using a group table. Instead, I'm able to show rounded corners on a simple table.. the problem comes when table goes into edit mode and a delete button will not visible on the table.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Grouped tableView, Which is a common solution. Regarding the disappearance of the delete button, you need to publish your code here to debug.